# Grouping 3 JSONs into a JSON in GO

Tags: json, postgresql, go, slice

Now, I am writing GO for REST API

Now, I got 3 JSONs (str_data_table / str_all_col / str_all_domain) as below (These json is in slice datatype)

str_data_table

```
{
    "table" : "tablea",
    "table_type" : "pubilc"
}
```

str_all_col

```
[ 
    { 
        "table" : "tablea",
        "field" : "name",
        "type". : "string"
    },
    { 
        "table" : "tablea",
        "field" : "surname"
        "type". : "string"
    },
]
```

str_all_domain

```
[
    {
        "field" : "name",
        "domain" : "xxx",
        "element" : "jjjjj"
    },
    {
        "field" : "name",
        "domain" : "yyyy",
        "element" : "ssss"
    },
    {
        "field" : "surname",
        "domain" : "aaaaaa",
        "element" : "dddd"
    },
    {
        "field" : "surname",
        "domain" : "bbbbbb",
        "element" : "eeee"
    }
]
```

I need to grouping these 3 JSONs in to a single JSON like the below

```
{
    "table" : "tablea",
    "table_type" : "pubilc"
    "field" : [
        {
            "field" : "name",
            "type". : "string",
            "detail" : [
                {
                    "domain" : "xxx",
                    "element" : "jjjjj"
                },
                {
                    "domain" : "yyyy",
                    "element" : "ssss"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "field" : "surname",
            "type". : "string",
            "detail" : [ 
                {
                    "domain" : "aaaaaa",
                    "element" : "dddd"
                },
                {
                    "domain" : "bbbbbb",
                    "element" : "eeee"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I write code in GO using sqlc / chi-router / postgresql

```
    
    type str_domain_into struct {
        Domain  string
        Element string
    }

    type str_column_info struct {
        Field  string
        Type   string
        domain []str_domain_into
    }

    type str_table struct {
        Table     string
        TableType string
        column    []str_column_info
    }

    var mixData []str_table
    var w_mixData str_table
    var w_col str_column_info
    var w_domain str_domain_into

    for _, dataTable := range str_data_table {

        w_mixData.Table = dataTable.Table
        w_mixData.TableType = dataTable.TableType

        for _, dataColumn := range str_all_col {

            if dataTable.Table != dataColumn.Table {
                continue
            }

            w_col.Field = dataColumn.Field
            w_col.Type = dataColumn.Type

            for _, dataDomain := range str_all_domain {

                if dataColumn.Field != dataDomain.Field {
                    continue
                }

                w_domain.Domain = dataDomain.Domain
                w_domain.Element = dataDomain.Element

                w_col.domain = append(w_col.domain, w_domain)

            }

            w_mixData.column = append(w_mixData.column, w_col)

        }

        mixData = append(mixData, w_mixData)
    }

    respondWithJSON(w, 200, mixData)
```

However, The response of mixData is only two fields as below

```
{
    "table" : "tablea",
    "table_type" : "pubilc"
}
```

Additional code of func respondWithJSON

```
func respondWithJSON(w http.ResponseWriter, code int, payload interface{}) {
    // The payload is struct data

    data, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to marshal JSON response : %v", payload)
        w.WriteHeader(500)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(200)
    w.Write(data)
}
```

Please help. Thank you

The expected result should be as below

```
{
    "table" : "tablea",
    "table_type" : "pubilc"
    "field" : [
        {
            "field" : "name",
            "type". : "string",
            "detail" : [
                {
                    "domain" : "xxx",
                    "element" : "jjjjj"
                },
                {
                    "domain" : "yyyy",
                    "element" : "ssss"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "field" : "surname",
            "type". : "string",
            "detail" : [ 
                {
                    "domain" : "aaaaaa",
                    "element" : "dddd"
                },
                {
                    "domain" : "bbbbbb",
                    "element" : "eeee"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The struct filed should be exported, change to `Column` and `Domain`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@Trock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16182150/trock)

```
type str_column_info struct {
    Field  string
    Type   string
    domain []str_domain_into // Wrong
    Domain []str_domain_into // Correct
}

type str_table struct {
    Table     string
    TableType string
    column    []str_column_info // Wrong
    Column    []str_column_info // Correct
}
```